# How to calculate PWM duty cycle to compensate for different piezo sounder response at different frequencies?

Tags: pwm, frequency, piezo, decibel

How to calculate PWM duty cycle to compensate for different piezo sounder response at different frequencies?

I have a piezo sounder, and the datasheet informs me that I will get the following response:

Frequency      Response
200Hz          74dB
1000Hz         81dB

If I set my PWM duty cycle to 100% at 200Hz to get 74dB, how do I calculate the PWM duty cycle required to give the same response of 74dB at 1000Hz?

Thanks kindly for any help.

Comment: Uh. If you set your PWM to either 0% or 100% at 200 Hz you get 0 Hz. Have you used PWM before? Do you understand what a piezo does and how it works? (https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/technical-articles/how-piezoelectric-speakers-work/ ) Do you know what a natural resonance frequency (or frequencies) is or what it might mean to operate something away from that frequency? You have some reading to do.

Comment: It's an inverting output. So 100% duty cycle is not DC.

Comment: Yes, I've used PWM before. It works fine on my current project. Just looking to add a few refinements.

Comment: Yes, I know what a resonant frequency is. That's why I need some kind of compensation to avoid one frequency being louder/quieter than the other.

Comment: Measure it with a SPL meter, and adjust accordingly. Seriously, there are going to be a ton of variables which influence a calculated answer.

Comment: @Tantalum: Jonk is correct. 0% PWM will result in 0 V continuous. 100% PWM will result in continuous V+ with no 0 V pulses. That is DC. If it is inverting then 100% will give you 0 V. That can be considered DC with a value of 0 A.

Comment: A piezo transducer sounds awful since it has many resonances that shriek. Most piezo transducers peak at about 4kHz with almost no sound level below 500Hz and a few narrow peaks above 6kHz. Use a normal dynamic tweeter (coil and magnet) instead with a crossover network, some sound excellent even without any equalization.

Answer (score 0):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ffb6AX.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This is a variable clock or an Astable Multivibrator or a Relaxation Oscillator.  Choose any buffer to suit the voltage or power level required.  CMOS has an impedance of ~300 Ohms for 74HC and ~50 Ohms for  74ALCxx ~5V

Answer (score 0):

A piezo sounder has a horrible frequency response. With a complicated **linear** EQ circuit I doubt you can make good sound, then it can feed a class-D (PWM) amplifier that powers the sounder. You did not post the part number or frequency response graph of your sounder, here is mine:
[image: piezo]